# MS Azure DevOps Server: No Agent Pool details visible when clicking on the Agent Pool

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-server-2022

Environment:
Azure DevOps Server 2022
19.225.34309.2 (AzureDevOps2022.1)

I am prototyping an MS Azure DevOps Server on-premises setup. No issues installing the product until it came to the creation of Build Agents.

I can see the Default Agent Pool:
[image: Agent Pool visible in Collection settings]

However, I see no pool details when I click on it:
[image: No Agent Pool details visible in Collection settings]

My account is a Collection Administrator:
[image: Accouint is a Collection Administrator]

No error messages and the DevOps portal continues to operate normally.

I am expecting to see pool details when clicking on the pool, including seeing the Agents tab and being able to choose "New Agent" like it is described here: [Download and configure the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops#azure-pipelines)

I’ve tried to access Agent Pool details through Project Settings with the same result. I have also created another agent pool: the newly created pool would be seen in the pool list along with the Default Pool, but no pool details would be shown if clicked on it.

I've checked the IIS Anonymous Authentication setting as @kevin suggested below. It was already set as Kevin suggested on the site level. Setting it to "Application Pool Identity" at the server level also did not help. Here are [results of IISReset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w792g.jpg).

[Browser console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5exiN.jpg)

Can you please help me resolve the issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be related to the IIS Configuration of the Azure DevOps Server.

Refer to the following steps to change the **Anonymous Authentication** to **Application pool identity** and check if it can work.

1. Open IIS Manager (inetmgr)
2. Navigate to **Sites > Azure DevOps Server**
3. Double click on the **Authentication** icon
4. Right Click on **Anonymous Authentication** and select **Edit...**
5. Change it to **Application pool identity**.

   For example:

   [image]
6. Use Administrator CMD to run the **IISRESET**  command.

Then you can navigate to the Agent Pool Page and check if the details will show.

**Update:**

You can refer to the following steps to grant the Azure DevOps Server User **Impersonate a client after authentication** permission.

1. Open **Local Security Policy** editor.
2. Navigate to **Security Settings>Local Policies>User Rights Assignment**
3. Double click on **Impersonate a client after authentication**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kevin for your response. Unfortunately, that did not help. The Anonymous Authentication was already set to Application Pool Identity on the Azure site. I checked the setting on the server level. It was set to the Specific User, so I changed it to Application Pool Identity as well and restarted the VM. The behavior I described above still persisted: no details was shown for the default Agent Pool. Would you suggest anything else?

Comment: @CrazyMike2023 Have you run the IISRESET command? After running command, will it still shows the same result?

Comment: Kevin, yes, did not help, same behavior persists.

Comment: When you click F12 to open browser Developer tool, can you see any error messages in console or network tab?

Comment: Kevin, I've added browser console content in the question.

Comment: @CrazyMike2023 You can try to grant the permission  Impersonate a client after authentication to the azure devops server user. Check the update in the answer and check if it can work

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT, sorry for the delay. I've checked server configuration: it is using the "Network Service" account. This account is already included into the list of accounts granted the "Impersonate a client after authentication" policy.

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT,hope you are doing ok. Can you please let me know if you have any more suggestions in relation to this problem? Many thanks!